# Using models in laravel 4

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4

Just really what the title says, does anybody have a decent explanation on how to use models properly in laravel 4? I'm fine with using the pre-existing User model. But I read somewhere that queries and such should be done in a model of your own.

So what I have is basically a form where you can make a status update (like facebook) and it stores it in a database but the query is run through the controller.

I want it to be done through a model.

Any information on this would be great! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a broad question and right place to learn about `how to use model in Laravel-4` is the [laravel site](http://laravel.com) itself, but anyways.

Actually, `model` is the the place where you should keep the business logic in any `MVC` framework, it could be database related or anything else that is the heart of the application and `controller` and `View` are just two parts of the application whose responsibility is only communicate to the model, fetch data and present it to the user but all the data processing should be done in the `model` and controller should be kept `slim` and `view` is only a mechanism to present the user a `UI`.

So, if you want to have a `User` model in your application (laravel-4) then you may extend it  from `Eloquent` like

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    // code goes here
}
```

and then call it's methods from the controller, like

```
$user = User::get(1);
```

then passing it to the view like

```
return View::make('viewname', $user);
```

That's it. But, if you think, where the `find` method come from then, it's because, you have extended the `Eloquent` model and in that `model` all the necessary methods (find e.t.c) are available and your `User` model inherited the behavior of `Eloquent` model, so you can use all the `methods` from `User` and it's not necessary to a single method in your `User` model unless you need to write some special methods for that `User` model, like `relationship` functions and so. well, the perfect place to seek help or to know the basic about it is the [Laravel site](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), try to understand it from there and if you fail or just stuck anywhere then come here to ask with specific problem. Also, check [Basic Database Usage](http://laravel.com/docs/database) and [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries).

BTW, you may check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000) for a detailed answer on `model` of `MVC`.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the extensive answer to my question. I will check out the links you put there THUMBS UP!

Comment: Late to the topic, but great explanation. Thank you.